# Divide a function into intervals such way that the figures under the graph on each interval have centers of mass in integers

Tags: integration, analytic-geometry, graphing-functions

Can we divide the real line into intervals $(a_i,b_i)$ such a way that for a given function $f(x)$ the figure under its graphic on each interval had center of mass in an integer?

The formula for center of mass is

$$x_i=\frac{\int_{a_i}^{b_i} x f(x) dx}{\int_{a_i}^{b_i} f(x) dx}$$

So we should find such $a_i, b_i$ that for each pair, the above expressed $x_i$ was an integer.

Is there a simple way?

Comment: I doubt there will be a simple way in general. It depends entirely on the function $f$, I think.

Comment: @String can we do it for function 1/x at least?

Comment: How many intervals do you want?

Comment: @Matthew Conroy this question is important only in case of infinite interval on which the function is defined.

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. Do you want one pair $(a_i,b_i)$, or many pairs? Is one enough?

Comment: @Matthew Conroy if the function is defiined on infinite interval, how you would divide it into one pair?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.  Thanks! It seems to me that as long as the center of mass over $(a,b)$ tends to infinity as b tends to infinity, this is doable.  For instance, with $f(x)=1/x$, the c.o.m. from $(1,b)$ is at $x=(b-1)/\log b$.  Since $(b-1)/\log b$ tends to infinity continuously as $b$ tends to $\infty$, you can definitely find a $b$ for which this is an integer (e.g., $b=10.34665192...$ yields an $x$ coordinate of $4$).   Using this as our $a_2$ value, we can then find $b_2=11.6802898043930...$ (putting the c.o.m. at $x=11$).  This process can be continued indefinitely.

Comment: @Matthew Conroy yes. The question is how to find a formula or an easy way. What particularly interests me is the sequence of areas of such intervals (if there are integers corresponding to no interval, then zeros should be in the sequence on their place).